# What is the best way to trigger a download of a safari extension?

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I have a Safari extension that I built that is properly packaged as a .safariextz. I want to trigger a download of the extension via javascript.

Currently, I am just using window.replace and pointing it to the extension URL. This causes a download, but the user must find the download and then start the installation process which pops the confirmation dialog.

Any ideas about simpler (for the user) ways of doing this install process that are started by Javascript?

I was amazed because Chrome and Firefox both have a much better install process for the user. I was hoping for something similar.

Comment: Apple uses a one-click installation process on their own extensions gallery. You might be able to figure out how it works and use it on your own site. Or not; Apple can be jerks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `safari.installExtension(id, url)` API. Take a look at extensions.apple.com, in their extensions.js file. It's nicely commented and clear, which is surprising and the API works as expected. The `id` is your extension namespace followed by your developer certificate ID and the `URL` can be the url on your own server.

> Edit: This function only seems to be available when ON the extensions.apple.com site. trying other ideas.

Comment: Hi
Any news regarding this topic, I'm trying to find a similar answer ... Thanks
Jerome